# Group visually data as columns while HTML0. rendered as row

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, lodash

In a VueJS component, I want to render the data which I receive from an API structured as shown below (array of objects).

```js
const data = [
  {
    "firstName": "Nick",
    "lastName": "Pappas",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
  },
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Stamos",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
  },
  {
    "firstName": "George",
    "lastName": "Papadopoulos",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
  }
]
```

My goal is to produce a "table-looking" layout with the significant requirement: every object isn't a row, it's a column.

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="table">
  <div class="photos table-row">
    <div class="table-cell p-3">
      photo1
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell p-3">
      photo2
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell p-3">
      photo3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="first-names table-row">
    <div class="table-cell p-3">
      George
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell p-3">
      Nick
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell p-3">
      John
    </div>
  </div>
</table>
```

How could one generate something similar to the above while using the Vue template directives? My hints are:

- Normalize the data? Create separate arrays for each property of all X persons?

```js
const groupedByKey = {
    "firstNames": ["Nick", "John", "George"],
    "lastNames": ["Pappas", "Stamos", "Papadopoulos"]
    "photos": ["...."]
}
```

- visually form columns is by using `flex-direction: column` on each company container.
  (The problem with this is it lacks all table properties with regards to element autosizing depending on the content of other elements of the row.)

This of course could be achieved by having one separate loop for each property, but for performance and maintenance reasons this is something that I wish to avoid.

I will upvote and accept answers that provide lodash methods to group the data per key as shown in the snipped but ideally if a CSS/HTML only way (of course using the Vue template directives as much as possible) is possible, it would be preferred.

Comment: You want to avoid looping each property, yet you're okay with grouping the data by key and then looping each of those properties. That's contradictory to me.

Comment: fair point! I guess I feel more comfortable when the JS part of the component does the heavy lifting and HTML's/template's job is rather simpler; I guess that's a fairly established best practice (?)

Comment: having a data structured with all values of each available key in the same array would probably mean I can render the template using table layout with 2 v-fors; one that runs on rows ( firstNames, lastNames, photos ) and one that runs on the values of each row ( Nick, John, George ) etc

Comment: Rendering items in a loop is not really heavy lifting. The property access is simple and requires no logic. I would just have two `v-for` loops: one to render the `photo` property of each item in a row, and then another for `firstName`, as seen in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-render-rows-of-data-d3tgps?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUserList.vue). That basically is doing what you propose to do with the other data structure.

Comment: @tony19 the example here is simplified just for SO, in reality there's 8-9 fields, so that would mean 8 loops

Answer (score 1):

Merge all objects to a single object by spreading the array into `_.mergeWith()`, and concatenating the values using the customizer function:

```js
const groupByKey = arr => _.mergeWith({}, ...arr, (
  a = [], b = []) => a.concat(b)
)

const data = [{"firstName":"Nick","lastName":"Pappas","photo":"https://via.placeholder.com/150"},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Stamos","photo":"https://via.placeholder.com/150"},{"firstName":"George","lastName":"Papadopoulos","photo":"https://via.placeholder.com/150"}]

const result = groupByKey(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

With Vanilla JS you can reduce the array to an object. On each iterate run the current object (`o`) through `Object.entries()`, and then iterate the entries with `Array.forEach()` and add them to the the relevant array. You can use [*Logical nullish assignment (??=)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) to init keys that don't exist yet.

```js
const groupByKey = arr => arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  Object.entries(o)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => {     
      (acc[k] ??= []).push(v)
    })
      
  return acc
}, {})

const data = [{"firstName":"Nick","lastName":"Pappas","photo":"https://via.placeholder.com/150"},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Stamos","photo":"https://via.placeholder.com/150"},{"firstName":"George","lastName":"Papadopoulos","photo":"https://via.placeholder.com/150"}]

const result = groupByKey(data)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I noticed that I can get an array of a certain group of keys by natively running `map` on the object; `data.map((item) => item.firstName)` `=>` `[ 'Nick', 'John', 'George' ]` so I guess I need to combine this with something like `Object.keys` ?

Comment: `Object.entries()` because you need the keys and the values. In addition, when you want to transform the form of an array, it usually calls for reduce. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is a viable solution here, despite your concern about auto-sizing issues. *(Feel free to point out those issues in my demo below)*

You could render the list of data with [`v-for`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for), where each iteration is a column:

```html
<template>
  <div class="user-table">
    <div class="user-column" v-for="col in data">
      <img class="photo" :src="col.photo" :alt="col.firstName">
      <div class="first-name">{{ col.firstName }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then use Flexbox to style `.user-table` and `.user-column`:

```css
.user-table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.user-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-render-rows-of-data?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUserList.vue)

Comment: first of all many thanks for the excellent demo. I forked it to illustrate the issues: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-render-rows-of-data-v7k8fc?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUserList.vue 
The data I have has inconsistent char lengths and each 'row' has to have a bg color..

Comment: I would have to use min-heights on rows to address alignment issues; it's possible but very quickly it may outweigh the pros of the flexbox solution; all these would be handled by a table layout (if the data was groomed)

Comment: You don't need min-height for that. Just use `justify-content: space-between` for the columns (see updated [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-render-rows-of-data-fyphul?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUserList.vue)).

Comment: Thank you for the fix but it seems to not hold up when you add more fields: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-render-rows-of-data-nqsrhe?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUserList.vue